# Animated splash screen for Android & iOS

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, android-12

To make an animation which can be used as splash screen for Android & iOS, I was thinking about using lotties (explained in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/native-splash-screen-in-flutter-using-lottie-121ce2b9b0a4)), but with Android 12 it seems like the tools used are deprecated and it's not really a good solution anymore.

I found [this workaround](https://github.com/vcaen/splashscreen-sample/tree/main/lottiesample) to still make it work, but from what I understand, the splash screen is now waiting for the animation to finish, which I know is a bad practice and I don't really want to do that (maybe there is a way to interrupt it?).

I have seen some packages on pub.dev, but the animated ones seem to not really replace the launch screen (the white screen by default) and just start after it.

So my question is : is there any other way to create one animation which can be used both on Android & iOS? (which would be a looping animation, interrupted when the app is ready).

Comment: Do you know [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)? It seems to have Android 12 support.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Yeah I do unfortunately it's only for static image